# .NET Core Entity Framework - Migration path --output-dir

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have successfully created a migration file using .NET Core class library by using command: `dotnet ef --startup-project ../Project.Web migrations add Init`

Because I register my db context in a different layer, (web layer), and have class library, I have to set my startup project to Project.Web.

After creating my initial migration it looks something like this:

[image]

But now I would like to move the migration folder `Project.Data/Migrations` to `Project.Data/Database/Migrations`

I have tried using the output-dir parameter:

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../Project.Web --output-dir Database migrations add Init
```

But then I get:

> dotnet : Unrecognized option '--output-dir'

**Startup** (in a different project, business layer)

```
public static IServiceCollection InjectBusinessContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
{
    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<ProjectContext>((serviceProvider, options) => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Database")).UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider));

    return services;
}
```

**Context** (data layer)

```
public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Account> Account { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move it (and optionally change the namespace of the classes). New migrations will follow suit with the previous migration. (Ditto for the model snapshot.) Yes, it's that awesome. ;)

Comment: That is.. Awesome. Cheers.